# Programmatically changing zoom/pan in UIWebView

Tags: iphone

I am currently investigating the potential for programmatically adjusting the zoom level and on which area of the page the zoom is panned to. Is this possible either by manipulating the UIWebView or by firing custom javascript calls to the embedded browser?

Comment: Is this for a website or for a native app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked around a lot for the same thing, and I haven't had a lot of luck. `UIWebView` is not descended from `UIScrollView`, so that type of manipulation is out. By the way, you probably don't mean to be asking about MobileSafari, since as a developer you don't have access to that programmatically. MobileSafari uses a UIWebView, not the other way around.

Good luck on figuring this one out! If you do, be sure to post the answer here. :)

Comment: Charybdis - Sorry, should have been more clear. This is a for a native app that will be including an UIWebView object, however I am led to believe that I can fire off custom javascript calls into the pages I have loaded into the UIWebView, so wondered if it was possible via the js route.

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically zoom the UIWebview by grabbing its UIScrollView and telling that to zoom.  You can access the scrollview this way:

```
scrollView = [webView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
```

After that you just manipulate the scrollview like you normally would. I just did this last week, and I have the zooming working correctly but it currently just zooms to the top left corner, so I'm still trying to figure out how to do centerpoint part of it. If you need any more help with the zooming let me know and I can try to explain it more.